# "Table name pattern can not be NULL or empty" in java

Tags: java, mysql

When I want to get tables from databaseMetaData,I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Table name pattern can not be NULL or empty.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:545)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getTables(DatabaseMetaData.java:3836)
at FindUserTables.main(FindUserTables.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

This my code,my jdbc driver is mysql-connector-java-6.0.5-bin.jar.What happened?

```
import java.sql.*;
public class FindUserTables {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javabook ?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "123456");
        System.out.println("Database connected");
        DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rsTables = dbMetaData.getTables(null, null, null,
                new String[] {"TABLE"});
        System.out.print("User tables: ");
        while (rsTables.next())
            System.out.print(rsTables.getString("TABLE_NAME") + " ");
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rsTables = dbMetaData.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rsTables .next()) {
  System.out.print(rsTables.getString(3) + " ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 11):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-properties-changed.html says under "Properties that have their default values changed:"

> `nullNamePatternMatchesAll` is now `false` by default

So one way to fix it is by appending `?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true` to the connection string (replace the `?` with `&` if it's not the first property in the connection string).

Comment: Thank you, your comment is really helpful for me during `liquibase generateChangeLog` command.

Comment: Great, this worked very well for me, when using the outdated ddlutils.

Answer (score 5):

In your JDBC URL add this

```
nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true

jdbc:mysql://<Host>/<DB>?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `null` values to `dbMetaData.getTables()`, when one of them (the second last) should be the table name pattern (try `"%"` for all) and as the message says, it can't be `null` or empty.

It seems to be  configurable according to (an older) the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.35/com/mysql/jdbc/DatabaseMetaData.java#4562), but I guess you should be explicit with the parameter just to be sure.

Comment: Are you sure about this?  [This](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/databasemetadata.html) and several other tutorials mention that all _four_ parameters can be `null`.  Maybe the API has changed.

Comment: I'm just stating what the driver says. The API doesn't say anything about the allowed or disallowed null-ness of the variables, but the error message sure seems to think null isn't allowed.

Comment: I believe you're right, just thought it odd that the tutorials would give such information.

Comment: Seems to be [configurable](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.35/com/mysql/jdbc/DatabaseMetaData.java#4562) whether null acts as `%` or if it needs to be set explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer