# Error "Table name pattern can not be NULL or Empty" when trying to generate changelog file from existing project

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, liquibase

I have trouble to generate changelog file from MySQL server with this command

```
liquibase 
--driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
--classpath=\path\to\mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar 
--changeLogFile=com\example\db.changelog.yaml
--url=jdbc:mysql:http://hostip:3306/schemaName 
--username=scott 
--password=tiger 
generateChangeLog
```

This always returns - "Table name pattern can not be NULL or Empty", and I got only 2 tables and both of them got a name.

Maybe I need to mention that this whole DDL was made by Hibernate i just export and import the DDL to the schema.

It's a Spring Boot project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a recent version of MySQL driver. In these versions the value of the nullNamePatternMatchesAll parameter is false by default. I'm not sure if you can force your JDBC conection string and somehow add ?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true to your url, making it effectively

> --url=jdbc:mysql://hostip:3306/schemaName?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true

or if that does not work, downgrade your JDBC driver.

This is a problem of the JDBC metadata retrieval layer, which Liquibase is obviously dependent on.

For further information, look for example here: ["Table name pattern can not be NULL or empty" in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084633/table-name-pattern-can-not-be-null-or-empty-in-java)

Comment: did what you suggested both ways throws exeption "parameters must start with a '--'"

Comment: Do you have the two dashes in the call, like --url=jdbc:... ?

Comment: you mean like --nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true? because its a syntax error, and when i do this in 1 line like --url=jdbc:mysql://hostip:3306/schemaName?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true i gain ana exeption  "parameters must start with a '--'"

Comment: @Aharon No, the url parameter seems ok. But the error message you get sounds like you forgot a -- in front of a parameter name. Or some of your parameters contains a space so that liquibase believes those are two parameters.

Comment: I tried both ways with the -- at the start and on the URL line and nothing help

Comment: ./liquibase --driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" --classpath="/home/vonkad/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-6.0.6/mysql-connector-java-6.0.6-bin.jar" --changeLogFile="cdb.changelog.yaml" --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/std_xforms?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true" --username="std_xforms" --password="fakepasswd" generateChangeLog

Comment: I bet you have some forgotten a space somewhere.

Comment: OMG i just needed to put all the params in "" now its working!!! i got a change log file... now how i make Spring modify and create chagelogs?

Comment: Well, I guess that would be worth another question. With a clear specs what you have to do. I have a Spring project that has liquibase in pom.xml and then liquibase called in initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add property: `defaultSchemaName=yourSchemaName`

Comment: i did this is just an example my driver is --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver --classpath=someclasspath\mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar

Comment: You should put your code in the question, so that is clear what your problem is. You should also provide your changelog.xml and changeset id on which error occurs.

Comment: OK edited to what i really put in the command line, idont heve any changelog.xml and changeset id. i trying to generate very first changelog-master

Comment: you know what it could be?

Comment: So delete the db name from the URL and do -- and you property

Comment: same problem "Table name pattern can not be NULL or Empty" there is a way to show you my db tables? i got just 2 tables in this schema both heve name